# Filling in an array from a list with uneven catagories

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, list

I have data in the format of an ID number, and a geographic area (MSOA) which is in the format in the image below.

List of Data:
[image: List of Data]

As you can see, there are differing numbers of MSOA for each ID, hence the list is not evenly spaced.

I need to use the data to fill in an array with ID in the columns, and MSOA in the rows. I have all MSOAs in the rows (Not just ones matched with IDs) and need the array to display a 1 or a 0 depending on whether the ID has match for that MSOA.

I've attached an image of what sort of output I need:

Array output:
[image: Array output]

Can anybody help with some code to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Did you try to Transpose the data? There is an Excel command for this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a formula:

```
=IF(AND(E$1=$A2,$D2=$B2),1,0)
```

or a pivot table:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help! The formula didn't seem to work, something do uneven numbers of IDs and MSOAs, which often overlap. The pivot table however was of use, I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks for your help.